# How to configure generic type parameters in xml configuration for castle-windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, xml-configuration

I've following code:

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public ITest<string> Test { get; set; }
}

[Convertible]
public interface ITest<T>
{
    T Param { get; set; }
}

[Convertible]
public class Test<T> : ITest<T>
{
    public T Param { get; set; }
    public string OtherParam { get; set; }
}
```

And I'd like to use it

```cs
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
var t = container.Resolve<TestClass>();
```

I don't want use Fluent configuration but xml-configuration. Also I'd like to escape explicit registration of components for ITest. It's lloks like that it can be configured with only one component registration (TestClass) and all parameters can be provided in in <parameters> node. But currently I failed to create working configuration, it creates *null* TestClass object or TestClass with Test property set to *null*.

My configuration:

```xml
  <component id="Service.Main"
         type="ConsoleApplication1.TestClass"
         lifestyle="transient">
    <parameters>
      <foo>foo string</foo>
      <Test>
        <Param>param string</Param>
        <OtherParam>sdgsdfgdf</OtherParam>
      </Test>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

Maybe someone can advise right configuration? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I got sources for 3.2.0 version.
Add simple console application and check different versions with debugging.

Here is working solution:

```xml
  <component id="Service.Main"
         type="ConsoleApplication1.TestClass"
         lifestyle="transient">
    <parameters>
      <foo>foo string</foo>
      <Test>
        <parameters type="ConsoleApplication1.Test`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], ConsoleApplication1">
          <Param>param string</Param>
          <OtherParam>sdgsdfgdf</OtherParam>
        </parameters>
      </Test>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

Important notes:

1. **We should use  for subsequent complex properties**, otherwise it can't "see" all list of parameters. It get only first child: [ConfigurationParametersInspector.cs, line 58](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/ModelBuilder/Inspectors/ConfigurationParametersInspector.cs#L58)
2. **We should explicitly set the type of parameter that represented by property with interface type**. We can expect that *type* attribute should be used for &ltTest> node but in fact, only child XML nodes passed to the method that choose type for property.

   - If we do not provide type attribute, we fail with *ConverterException*: [DefaultComplexConverter.cs, line 83](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/SubSystems/Conversion/DefaultComplexConverter.cs#L83)
   - Here we we get <parameters> with *type* attribute (and loose parent node attributes, so if we set type for <Test> it will be lost: [ConfigurationParametersInspector.cs, line 59](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/ModelBuilder/Inspectors/ConfigurationParametersInspector.cs#L59)
   - And here is the method that chose interface implementation depending on type attribute: [DefaultComplexConverter.cs, line 75](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/SubSystems/Conversion/DefaultComplexConverter.cs#L75)

Anyway configuration checked with 3.2.0 and it works.